# Plotting a 3D surface from data

Tags: c++, r, dataframe, plot, octave

I have written C++ code to numerically solve a PDE. I would like to plot the result. I have outputted the data to an ascii file, as 3 columns of numbers. The x-coordinate, the y-coordinate and the z-coordinate. This might look like

```
0.01 7 -3
-12 1.2 -0.24
...
```

I often have in excess of 1000 data points. I want to plot a surface. I was able to load the data in both R and octave. In R scatterplot3D worked, and in octave plot3 worked. However, I wish to produce a surface, and not distinct points (scatterplot3d), or a curve (plot3). I am struggling to get mesh or surf to work from data in octave. I am looking for a simple way to plot a surface in 3D space with octave, R, C++ or any other program.

Comment: May I suggest giving https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus a try? I haven't tried it myself but it looks promising. In theory it should mirror the octave / matplotlib commands. There's a few `surf` examples on that page :)

Comment: That looks very interesting, I'll see how it goes

Comment: Having said that, I am assuming the mistake you're making is the typical one where the X and Y in `surf(X,Y,Z)` need to be a fully defined grid, rather than X and Y coordinate vectors respectively. (i.e. X, Y and Z all need to be matrices of the same size). Read carefully the [relevant page in the octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html). If what you have is x,y,z tuples instead, effectively your best bet would be to use `interpn` to interpolate these values onto a regular X,Y grid first, and then use surf to plot the interpolated Z values.

Comment: I looked in a bit more detail and have had some more success with octave now after using griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could coerce the data into the correct format for plotting with the base R function `persp`. This requires a vector of unique x values, a vector of unique y values, and a matrix of z values which is a `length(unique(x))` by `length(unique(y))` matrix.

Suppose your data looks like this:

```r
x    <- y <- seq(-pi, pi, length = 20)
df   <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
df$z <- cos(df$x) + sin(df$y)

head(df)
#>           x         y           z
#> 1 -3.141593 -3.141593 -1.00000000
#> 2 -2.810899 -3.141593 -0.94581724
#> 3 -2.480205 -3.141593 -0.78914051
#> 4 -2.149511 -3.141593 -0.54694816
#> 5 -1.818817 -3.141593 -0.24548549
#> 6 -1.488123 -3.141593  0.08257935
```

Then you can create a matrix like this:

```
z <- tapply(df$z, list(df$x, df$y), mean)
```

So your plot would look like this:

```
persp(unique(df$x), unique(df$y), z, 
      col = "gold", theta = 45, shade = 0.75, ltheta = 90)
```

[image]

If your x and y co-ordinates are not nicely aligned, then a more general approach would be:

```r
z <- tapply(df$z, list(cut(df$x, 20), cut(df$y, 20)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

persp(as.numeric(factor(levels(cut(df$x, 20)), levels(cut(df$x, 20)))), 
      as.numeric(factor(levels(cut(df$y, 20)), levels(cut(df$y, 20)))), 
      z, col = "gold", theta = 45, shade = 0.75, ltheta = 90, xlab = "x", 
      ylab = "y")
```

Comment: I like the bit on creating the matrix as that was where I was having trouble with r. However, doesn't persp require increasing x and y values? My data points may be quite random.

Comment: @epiliam yes, so you pass the sorted unique `x` and sorted unique `y` values to `persp` (or use `cut` to get a group of them together). You use these unique values as the columns and rows of your z matrix. If you have some sample data you can add to your question in `dput` format, I could show you how to do that if you can't get the above solution to work for you.